# mariadb - JSON Column update element inside a nested list

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

I have the following data in a json column:

```
[
    ["model-1", 0.06232], 
    ["model-2", 0.33587], 
    ["model-3", 0.04962], 
    ["model-4", 0.235], 
    ["model-5", 0.31719]
]
```

My goal is to prepend a string to the first element of each inner list so that the output becomes:

```
[
    ["somestr/model-1", 0.06232], 
    ["somestr/model-2", 0.33587], 
    ["somestr/model-3", 0.04962], 
    ["somestr/model-4", 0.235], 
    ["somestr/model-5", 0.31719]
]
```

I have been able to "extract" the first elements using mariadb JSON_EXTRACT as follows:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(factors, '$[*][0]') FROM my_table;
```

But could not get any further.

Is it possible to achieve this using mariadb / mysql JSON functions? Or am I better off doing this on the application level?

Comment: You want to change the database or an in memory array?

Comment: In the database I have a json column in a table, I would like to change it into a new column then drop the original if it is impossible to update it directly

Comment: One option is [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=3ab1ec8362a35ad03688e310618464e2).

Comment: Don't bury values in JSON if you regularly need to update them.

Comment: @RickJames I have unfortunately inherited the system in this state..

Comment: There are two ways of coping with an inherited system -- Repeatedly spending effort with its quirks; or spend a one-time effort to improve on them.